# How to highlight the menu item in menu

Tags: html, css

I am using a CSS menu in a web page and I want to know how to highlight the selected menu item of the CSS menu. I have pasted the HTML/CSS code below. Can anyone help me by posting the code snippet for highlighting the menu item?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Generated by Pure CSS Menu.com : Free CSS Drop Down Menu Generator</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Online CSS Menu Maker. Create No-Javascript, 100% CSS Dropdown Menu in seconds! Horizontal css menu & Vertical css menu." />
</head>
<body bgcolor="#ffffff">



<!-- Start PureCSSMenu.com STYLE -->
<style>
#pcm{display:none;}
ul.pureCssMenu ul{display:none}
ul.pureCssMenu li:hover>ul{display:block}
ul.pureCssMenu ul{position: absolute;left:-1px;top:98%;}
ul.pureCssMenu ul ul{position: absolute;left:98%;top:-2px;}
ul.pureCssMenu,ul.pureCssMenu ul {
    margin:0px;
    list-style:none;
    padding:0px 1px 1px 0px;
    background-color:#A5A5A5;
    background-repeat:repeat;
    border-color:#A6A6A6;
    border-width:0px;
    border-style:solid;
}
ul.pureCssMenu table {border-collapse:collapse}ul.pureCssMenu {
    display:block;
    zoom:1;
    float: left;
}
ul.pureCssMenu ul{
    width:0px;
}
ul.pureCssMenu li{
    display:block;
    margin:1px 0px 0px 1px;
    font-size:0px;
}
ul.pureCssMenu a:active, ul.pureCssMenu a:focus {
outline-style:none;
}
ul.pureCssMenu a, ul.pureCssMenu li.dis a:hover, ul.pureCssMenu li.sep a:hover {
    display:block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    border-width:0px;
    border-color:#FCEEB0;
    border-style:solid;
    text-align:left;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:5px;
    _padding-left:0;
    font:normal 11px Arial;
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration:none;
    cursor:pointer;
}
ul.pureCssMenu span{
    overflow:hidden;
}
ul.pureCssMenu li {
    float:left;
}
ul.pureCssMenu ul li {
    float:none;
}
ul.pureCssMenu ul a {
    text-align:left;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
ul.pureCssMenu li.sep{
    text-align:left;
    padding:0px;
    line-height:0;
    height:100%;
}
ul.pureCssMenu li.sep span{
    float:none; padding-right:0;
    width:3;
    height:100%;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:#A6A6A6;   background-image:none;}
ul.pureCssMenu ul li.sep span{
    width:100%;
    height:3;
}
ul.pureCssMenu li:hover{
    position:relative;
}
ul.pureCssMenu li:hover>a{
    background-color:#FF1C1C;
    border-color:#4C99AB;
    border-style:solid;
    font:normal 11px Arial;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration:none;
}
ul.pureCssMenu li a:hover{
    position:relative;
    background-color:#FF1C1C;
    border-color:#4C99AB;
    border-style:solid;
    font:normal 11px Arial;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration:none;
}
ul.pureCssMenu li.dis a {
    color: #AAAAAA !important;
}
ul.pureCssMenu img {border: none;float:left;_float:none;margin-right:5px;width:16px;
height:16px;
}
ul.pureCssMenu ul img {width:16px;
height:16px;
}
ul.pureCssMenu img.over{display:none}
ul.pureCssMenu li.dis a:hover img.over{display:none !important}
ul.pureCssMenu li.dis a:hover img.def {display:inline !important}
ul.pureCssMenu li:hover > a img.def  {display:none}
ul.pureCssMenu li:hover > a img.over {display:inline}
ul.pureCssMenu a:hover img.over{display:inline}
ul.pureCssMenu a:hover img.def{display:none}
ul.pureCssMenu span{
    display:block;
    background-image:url(./images/arrv_blue_2.gif);
    background-position:right center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
   padding-right:8px;}
ul.pureCssMenu li:hover>a>span{ background-image:url(./images/arrv_white_2.gif);
}
ul.pureCssMenu a:hover span{    _background-image:url(./images/arrv_white_2.gif)}
ul.pureCssMenu ul span,ul.pureCssMenu a:hover table span{background-image:url(./images/arr_blue_2.gif)}
ul.pureCssMenu ul li:hover > a span{    background-image:url(./images/arr_white_2.gif);}
ul.pureCssMenu li a.pureCssMenui0{
font:n;
}
ul.pureCssMenu li a.pureCssMenui0:hover{
font:o;
}
</style>
<!-- End PureCSSMenu.com STYLE -->



<!-- Start PureCSSMenu.com MENU -->
<ul class="pureCssMenu pureCssMenum">
    <li class="pureCssMenui0"><a class="pureCssMenui0" href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="pureCssMenui0"><a class="pureCssMenui0" href="#">About us</a></li>
    <li class="pureCssMenui0"><a class="pureCssMenui0" href="#">FAQ</a></li>
    <li class="pureCssMenui0"><a class="pureCssMenui0" href="#">Gallery</a></li>
    <li class="pureCssMenui0"><a class="pureCssMenui0" href="#">Forums</a></li>
    <li class="pureCssMenui0"><a class="pureCssMenui0" href="#">Contact us</a></li>
</ul>
<a id="pcm" href="http://www.purecssmenu.com/">CSS Drop Down Menu by PureCSSMenu.com</a>
<!-- End PureCSSMenu.com MENU -->



<!-- (c) 2009, PureCSSMenu.com -->


<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hi you can create a class active and give to same **pureCssMenui0:hover**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess what you want is to have class

```
ul.pureCssMenuSelected {
   //whatever the selection should look like
}
```

Then, in each html page you go to, you add that class to the option the page refers too.

```
<ul class="pureCssMenu pureCssMenum">
    <li class="pureCssMenui0"><a class="pureCssMenui0 pureCssMenuSelected" href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="pureCssMenui0"><a class="pureCssMenui0" href="#">About us</a></li>
    <li class="pureCssMenui0"><a class="pureCssMenui0" href="#">FAQ</a></li>
    <li class="pureCssMenui0"><a class="pureCssMenui0" href="#">Gallery</a></li>
    <li class="pureCssMenui0"><a class="pureCssMenui0" href="#">Forums</a></li>
    <li class="pureCssMenui0"><a class="pureCssMenui0" href="#">Contact us</a></li>
</ul>
```

This because of course the html has no way of guessing what do you mean by selected item.

P.S.: Probably you probably don't want to use an anchor link on that option.

P.P.S.: As others mentioned, if you are using the links in the same page, you need to use javascript. In jQuery, the code could be:

```
$('a').click(function() { 
    $('.pureCssMenuSelected').removeClass('pureCssMenuSelected');
    $(this).addClass('pureCssMenuSelected'); 
}
```

Also, add the class pureCssMenuSelected to the initally selected item, directly in the HTML. Finally, if you use this last solution, call it something other than *pure* CSS menu :)

Answer (score 1):

If you use this links in a single page You can use jquery also

```
$('.pureCssMenu li a').click(function () {
$('.pureCssMenu li a').removeClass('selected');
$(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

(or)

You are redirecting to another page create one class and add that class in the redirected page for respective link. 
I hope this will help You...

Comment: That doesn't work, since you are removing and adding the class to the same element that was clicked. Each time you clicked it will always get selected - for good, will never unselect.

Comment: You could respond to my coment so it won't seem like it didn't make sense now that you edited my answer :D Though you still have a problem. Now that you are adding classes to both li and a, by not separating, it will remove the class selected from the li or a previously selected, which pertain to the same option. So only one of the elements (either a or li) will have the class.

Answer (score 1):

If you using the menu in all the pages separately, you can add a `class` which highlights the relevant item from the menu as `webdreamer` explains above.

If you using menu as a control which place in the  master page, you should find the current page and add the class manually.
 If you are ok to use `JQuery` you can do this item [Click](http://api.jquery.com/click/) by using [.addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) and 
[.removeClass()](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)

Comment: The minimum code (I think): 
$('a').click(function() { $('.pureCssMenuSelected').removeClass('pureCssMenuSelected');
$(this).toggleClass('pureCssMenuSelected'); 
}